How to Apply conditional formatting formula Row By Row?
Hi I have a worksheet of 1080 rows and I want to apply conditional formatting row by row to check the price increase in each row.
When I am selecting the whole range and putting formula it is showing the price change in whole range, but I need it for individual item, so need it by row by row.

In the image in Row 22 the price is getting increased. I want to highlight each row from 3 to 1080. I will need a VBA code for same, but not able to figure out a code to select row one by one and for applying formula in each row individually.

I'd build it for the first row using relative referencing and then apply it to the whole range.  Could you edit your question and include the formula you're using?

As "R22" (value 5.51) is smaller than "Q22" (value 11.02), you can't say that row "22" is increasing, can you?

Hi, I am using conditional formatting in this case. I just want to see the change in values relatively for each row. Please suggest me if there is any better and quicker way.

You only ask for help, without carefully reading the comments and do what suggested... You must help us to help you! Please, "Could you edit your question and include the formula you're using?". Doing that, we can show you how to adapt the formula. Otherwise, it is more complicated (than it should) to try understanding the logic you try applying, only looking to a picture.

Try this code:
Sub ApplyColorScale()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("B3:U3")
    With rng1
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1)
            .Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            .FormatColor.Color = 8109667  '7039480
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2)
            .Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
            .Value = 50
            .FormatColor.Color = 8711167
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3)
            .Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            .FormatColor.Color = 7039480  ' 8109667
        End With
    End With
    rng1.Copy
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 4 To 10  ' 1080
       Range("B" & i & ":U" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, SkipBlanks:=False
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


Is this what you need?
